# Let $(x_n)_{x\in\mathbb N}$, such that $x_{n+1}=x_n-\arctan(x_n)$ with $x_0>0$. Prove that $x_n$ is bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, upper-lower-bounds

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, $f(x)=x-\arctan(x)$.
>   Consider the sequence $(x_n)_{x\in\mathbb N}$, defined as $ x_0>0$ and $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$. Prove that  $x_n$ is bounded and calculate $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n$.

I know that $f(x)$ is increasing on $\mathbb R$ and it's positive for $x>0$. That means $x_n$ is increasing and positive as well, since $x_0>0$. To prove convergence I know that I have to show that the series is $(1)$ bounded and $(2)$ monotone. $x_n$ is bounded below by $0$ and clearly increasing but I would think it has no upper bound? This clearly is wrong, what am I missing?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: $(x_n)$ is *not* increasing.

Comment: @MartinR how come

Comment: I should write answers, not comments :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that since $x>\arctan(x)$ for $x>0$ ($f(0)=0$ and you already noted that $f$ is increasing), it follows that for $x_0>0$ and $n\geq 0$, we have that $x_n>0$ and 
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\arctan(x_n)< x_n$$
that is $(x_n)$ is positive and **strictly decreasing**. You can easily show that its limit is zero.